# Why does my bathroom exhaust fan blow downward?

Tags: ceiling, exhaust-fan, exhaust

Replaced exhaust fan and now air blows down into bathroom vs. out the exhaust vent.

Comment: Unless DC current and wired it backwards, would think it was placed upside down.

Comment: There are direction-changeable AC replacement motors, as well as ones that are not the same rotation direction as the original, but which can't be changed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are also in-line fans - it's not one of those, is it?

Answer (score 3):

It is installed incorrectly.

Whether it is an electrical connection or incorrect positioning of the motor we cannot tell without any pics.

A guess with high probability is that you installed the damper, ( the part that has the trap door and connects to the conduit to vent outside.) the wrong way.
The door probably get blown shut when the fan is turned on, rather than blown open.   If the damper door is shut the air will be forced out of the fan box and into the bathroom.
Check the damper operation first.